# When am using MediaPlayer, it shows " E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails " error . How to solve it?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

i read mp3 file from raw directory, it works fine but when am start media player at every time show some error ( is below on ).

My code is...

```
player1 = MediaPlayer.create(view.getContext(), R.raw.song1);
player2 = MediaPlayer.create(view.getContext(), R.raw.song2);
PlaySound(player1):

public void PlaySound(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ){
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
       mediaPlayer.start();
      }
}
```

Erorr is..

```
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
```

advance thanks,
i hope anyone can help me..

Comment: am using gradle 4.4 latest version

Comment: those error only showed on when am initialised MediaPlayers, please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solution was to restart tablet where I tested it, then it worked well.